# How to control TableView in View in Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview

1. I made a single view project.
2. I added a `UIView` object in View
3. I add a `UITableView` object in View.
4. I made a `TableViewController` Cocoa Touch file to create cells automatically.
5. To link `TableViewController` and the `UITableView`, I tried to change a table View class to `TableViewController` by using `Identity Inspector`, but it didn't work. Not a single class showed up.

**Question 1:** Why can't I change the table view class?

**Question 2:** How can I control both the view and the table view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You cannot change the class for tableView because the object is of type **UITableView** and you are trying to set it's class of type **UITableViewController**

2) to control both View and TableView, you can set the outlet for it.

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDatasource {
    // Connect the outlets to storyboard's YourViewController UI
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet var yourView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      // Set delegate and datasource and implement the delegate methods
      self.tableView.dataSource = self
      self.tableView.delegate = self

      // Handle the view properties for yourView here
      self.yourView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }
}
```

Hope it helps